# Inversion of a Toeplitz tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Currently, I am working on solving a PDE using the [finite element method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) (FEM) and facing the problem of finding the inverse of the following Toeplitz tridiagonal matrix

$$\mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b &   &   & & & 0 \\
    b & a & b &   & & & \\
      & b & a & b & & & \\
      &   & b & a & & & \\
      &   &   &   & \ddots & & \\
      &   &   &   &   & a & b \\
    0 &   &   &   &   & b & a \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Basically, this matrix has diagonal elements are all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and every elements adjacent to the diagonal elements are $b \in \mathbb{R}$, the rest are all zeros.

I tried using Newton's method (the inverse matrix of $\mathbf{M}$ is determined by the limit of $\mathbf{X}_n$ where $n$ to infinity of the sequence $\mathbf{X}_{n+1} = \mathbf{X}_n(2\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{M}\mathbf{X}_n)$) but this method is not very good with large matrix (or perhaps my coding skill is terrible). So I was wondering is there another method to find the inversion of this type of matrix?

For more detail about FEM (on 1D case), you can visit [here](http://mitran-lab.amath.unc.edu/courses/MATH762/bibliography/LinTextBook/chap6.pdf)

Comment: Do you need the inverse or are you trying to solve a system of equations?  If you are solving a system of equations this may help: [Tridiagonal matrix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm)

Comment: Sparsity is usually not upheld in an inverse. You could use iterative methods if you are trying to solve a linear equation. If you need some kind of inverse matrix, you could to implement an incomplete lu factorization (uphelds the sparsity)

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Cool, this is want I'm looking for. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: How large is your matrix? Why do you need to invert it?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo On average, the size of this matrix is around $1000\times 1000$. And the reason I need to find the inverse of it is to solve the coefficients vector $\mathbf{c}$ of the linear system $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{b}$, from there I can determine the approximated function $\tilde{u}(x) = \sum_{j} c_j\phi_j(x)$ of $u(x)$ in the boundary value problem $-\Delta u = f$ in $\Omega$, $u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$. This is the main idea of Galerkin's method to numerically solve PDE.

Edit: Fixed $u|_{\partial\Omega} = g$ to $u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$

Comment: Please include the background and motivation in the question itself.